# Connection failure when using strophe with ejabberd bosh to connect to jid account on localhost

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I have installed ejabberd on my machine and its running fine.

```
localhost:5280/admin

localhost:5280/http-bind
```

It is also displaying "ejabberd mod_http_bind An implementation of XMPP over BOSH (XEP-0206)" I guess it's working fine.

When I try to create a connection with Strophe I get the connection status as `CONNFAIL`.

My code goes as follow :

```
var conn = new Strophe.Connection('http://localhost:5280/http-bind');
conn.connect(data.jid, data.password, function (status) {

// jid=user@localhost


if(status===Strophe.Status.CONNECTING){

alert('connecting...!!');

}

if(status===Strophe.Status.AUTHFAIL){

alert('auth failure...!!');

}

if(status===Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL){

alert('connection falied !!');

}}
```

I keep getting `CONNFAIL`.

I have also added proxypass for`http://localhost:5280/http-bind` in apache httpd.conf file.

I am not able to figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To debug whether ejabberd is really receiving your Bosh requests, restart ejabberd with `{log_level, 5}` (set this inside your `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg` file). Then as you are making connection to ejabberd using strophe, watch for logs by doing `tail -f /var/log/ejabberd/ejabberd.log`. If you don't see anything, it means your requests are failing somewhere within proxy context. If you do see something, kindly update your question with relevant logs for us to help you out better.

Alternately you can update `log_level` on the fly via ejabberd debug shell:

```
$ sudo ejabberdctl debug
....
Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
(ejabberd@localhost)1> ejabberd_loglevel:set(5).
{module,ejabberd_logger}
(ejabberd@localhost)2>
```

**Note:** I assumed standard installation paths for `ejabberd.cfg` and `ejabberd.log`. If you have an alternate install prefix, kindly update the paths accordingly.

Comment: Thanx for this debugging method...the issue got resolved...there was a problem with proxies for bosh in the apache configuration...

Comment: Ahhh, you should really say what the problem was! Having a very similar issue and would have loved to know what the solution was for you.